# How to replace Nouveau with NVIDIA GeForce GT 610 sound driver?

Tags: nvidia, 20.04, sound, initramfs, nouveau

On **Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS** I want to replace Nouveau with my VGA/soundcard [specific NVIDIA driver](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/168290/en-us) because the front jack socket for headphones only works on one channel. (Note that the jack worked fine in a previous Windows installation.)

It's this card:

```
$ lspci -nn | grep VGA
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GF119 [GeForce GT 610] [10de:104a] (rev a1)
```

And the Linux Nouveau driver appears to be:

```
$ cat /proc/asound/version
Advanced Linux Sound Architecture Driver Version k5.8.0-45-generic.
```

From NVIDIA I downloaded a .run file which throws the following error after executing (that was expected, though, because I know first Nouveau should be blacklisted).

```
nvidia-installer log file '/var/log/nvidia-installer.log'
creation time: Sun Mar 21 10:05:34 2021
installer version: 390.141

PATH: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin

nvidia-installer command line:
    ./nvidia-installer

Using: nvidia-installer ncurses v6 user interface
-> Detected 8 CPUs online; setting concurrency level to 8.
ERROR: An NVIDIA kernel module 'nvidia-drm' appears to already be loaded in your kernel.  This may be because it is in use (for example, by an X server, a CUDA program, or the NVIDIA Persistence Daemon), but this may also happen if your kernel was configured without support for module unloading.  Please be sure to exit any programs that may be using the GPU(s) before attempting to upgrade your driver.  If no GPU-based programs are running, you know that your kernel supports module unloading, and you still receive this message, then an error may have occured that has corrupted an NVIDIA kernel module's usage count, for which the simplest remedy is to reboot your computer.
ERROR: Installation has failed.  Please see the file '/var/log/nvidia-installer.log' for details.  You may find suggestions on fixing installation problems in the README available on the Linux driver download page at www.nvidia.com.
```

Following a [how-to on Tecmint](https://www.tecmint.com/install-nvidia-drivers-in-linux/) to blacklist Nouveau I added a line `"blacklist nouveau"` into the `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`. Their next step is backing up the `initramfs-*` and creating a new one. However, I couldn't find any `/boot/initramfs-*` so I backed up the `initrd.img-5.8.0-45-generic`.

I followed the method the how-to is showing to create a new `initramfs` using `dracut`, giving me a nice **kernel panic unknown-block(0,0)** after a reboot attempt. I was able to fix it by restoring the `initrd*` backup with a live USB.

Seems I'm stuck here. Is there a working method to install the NVIDIA driver?

Comment: By front jack socket are you referencing a part of the computer or this card? If it is not in some way attached to the card how will the driver effect it?

Comment: @David Wow, front jack socket is of course attached to the card., worked fine on a former win installation, thx.

Comment: You may want to add that info to your question.

Comment: @David Done...!